# How to integrate Azure AD Authentication with a Web API service whose service reference has been added automatically?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api2

I have an ASP.NET MVC website in which I have added a "Web API 2 OData Controller with Actions, using Entity Framework".
This is the 1st set of code that is auto-generated.

I am calling this web API from a native client. I have added a reference to the Web API service through, Right Click, Add References. 
This is the 2nd bit that is auto-generated.

I've configured Azure AD authentication at the client side. This is working.

What I want to do now is: setup authentication for each Web API call based on the user who logged in from the client. So the client's access token needs to be passed from the client to the Web API, and this token should be used to authenticate further.

Note that a lot of the code is auto-generated. So the additions to code should have minimal effect on regeneration of the code, if possible.

Later on the Web API will use the user information to filter data based on his identity, and use role based identity as well.

Any pointers on how to start with this? I feel that all the various pieces are available, but how to gather them into a single solution is just out of grasp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container that is part of the auto-generated solution is where we need to pass the token.

Here's the code:

```
autogenContainer.BuildingRequest += (sender, args) =>
{
    args.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + access token retrieved from Azure);
};
```